# What is the best way to query the row count from Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am trying to get the number of rows for a given request.  The only obvious way I've found to accomplish it is:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context;
NSFetchRequest *request;

  ...

NSInteger count = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] count];
```

This seems wasteful to me, building an entire array of a large database's objects, just to find out how many there are.  Is there a better way to accomplish this, in a "Core Data" way?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

NSManagedObjectContext has a method which evaluates the count for a fetch request:

`- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error;`

See the [API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/countForFetchRequest:error:).

Comment: Ah of course, thank you very much.  I'm new to Core Data programming.  I was scouring for something inside the request object itself.